# Dynamic heap implementation with insert O(log n)

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity, heap

I'm trying to implement a Min Heap in Java, but between studying the complexity and the actual implementation, I realized that it is not clear to me how O (log n) insertion into the heap can be if a dynamic array (such as ArrayList) is used as the base structure.

I understand properly that insert operation in a Heap is O(log n) because we add new item at the end of the array, and we swap each item with his parent, up to a maximum of log n swaps.

But this theorically will works only if you have a base structure big enough to can insert new element: if we need to grow array, operation will take O(n). I know that add element in ArrayList has amortized O(1), but i want to know if is possible to implement the heap by accomplishing with real O(log n) insert operation.

I can use linkedList to accomplish O(1) in insert, but this means that other heap operations (like delete) will no longer have O(log n) complexity.

I also can use a fixed array, but this doesn't allow to insert in heap many elements as you want.

Is there another way?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a heap with nodes that are both part of a doubly linked list, and part of a threaded binary tree.

The heap maintains a reference to the root (head) and tail node.

So we can imagine a node having 5 pointers: `prev`, `next`, `left`, `right`, `parent`. However, we don't need to store `right` as -- when it exists -- it is equal to `left.next`.

Then the basic operations are as follows:

- Extract min:

  - Remember the value of the root
  - Get the last node (`tail`), copy its value to the root, and remove the node.
  - Perform the sift down operation to restore the heap property.
  - Return the value from the first step
- Add

  - Create a node with the given value and insert it as last node (and last child), so it becomes `tail`.
  - Perform the bubble up operation to restore the heap property.

Here is an implementation in Java:

```java
public class Node {
    int value;
    Node prev = null;
    Node next = null;
    Node parent = null;
    Node left = null;
    
    public Node(int val) { value = val; }
}
```

```java
class MinHeap {
    Node root = null;
    Node tail = null;
    
    void insert(int value) {
        Node node = new Node(value);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            tail = node;
        } else {
            // Insert node into tree
            Node parent = tail.parent != null ? tail.parent : root;
            if (parent.left != null && parent.left.next != null) {
                parent = parent.next;
            }
            if (parent.left == null) {
                parent.left = node;
            }
            node.parent = parent;
            // Insert node into doubly linked list
            node.prev = tail;
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
            // Restore heap property
            bubbleUp(node);
        }
    }
    
    Integer extract() {
        if (root == null) return null;
        int value = root.value;
        Node node = tail;
        if (node == root) { // Heap has only one node
            root = null;
            tail = null;
            return value;
        }
        // Remove node from tree
        if (node.parent.left == node) {
            node.parent.left = null;
        }
        // Remove node from doubly linked list
        tail = node.prev;
        tail.next = null;
        // Restore heap property
        root.value = node.value;
        bubbleDown(root);
        return value;
    }
    
    void bubbleUp(Node node) {
        int value = node.value;
        while (node.parent != null && node.parent.value > value) {
            node.value = node.parent.value;
            node = node.parent;
        }
        node.value = value;
    }
    
    void bubbleDown(Node node) {
        int value = node.value;
        while (node.left != null) {
            Node child = node.left;
            if (child.next != null && child.next.value < child.value) {
                child = child.next; // Right child
            }
            if (child.value >= value) break;
            node.value = child.value;
            node = child;
        }
        node.value = value;
    }
}
```

```java
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Demo
        MinHeap heap = new MinHeap();
        heap.insert(9);
        heap.insert(5);
        heap.insert(3);
        heap.insert(6);
        heap.insert(7);
        heap.insert(2);
        heap.insert(8);
        heap.insert(1);
        heap.insert(4);
        
        while (heap.root != null) {
            System.out.print(heap.extract() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Here is the same as a runnable JavaScript snippet:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.parent = null;
        this.left = null;
    }
}

class MinHeap {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }
    insert(value) {
        let node = new Node(value);
        if (!this.root) {
            this.root = node;
            this.tail = node;
        } else {
            // Insert node into tree
            let parent = this.tail.parent || this.root;
            if (parent.left?.next) {
                parent = parent.next;
            }
            if (!parent.left) {
                parent.left = node;
            }
            node.parent = parent;
            // Insert node into doubly linked list
            node.prev = this.tail;
            this.tail.next = node;
            this.tail = node;
            // Restore heap property
            this.bubbleUp(node);
        }
    }
    extract() {
        if (!this.root) return;
        let value = this.root.value;
        let node = this.tail;
        if (node == this.root) { // Heap has only one node
            this.root = null;
            this.tail = null;
            return value;
        }
        // Remove node from tree
        if (node.parent.left === node) {
            node.parent.left = null;
        }
        // Remove node from doubly linked list
        this.tail = node.prev;
        this.tail.next = null;
        // Restore heap property
        this.root.value = node.value;
        this.bubbleDown(this.root);
        return value;
    }
    bubbleUp(node) {
        let value = node.value;
        while (node.parent && node.parent.value > value) {
            node.value = node.parent.value;
            node = node.parent;
        }
        node.value = value;
    }
    bubbleDown(node) {
        let value = node.value;
        while (node.left) {
            let child = node.left;
            if (child.next && child.next.value < child.value) {
                child = child.next; // Right child
            }
            if (child.value >= value) break;
            node.value = child.value;
            node = child;
        }
        node.value = value;
    }
}

// Demo
let heap = new MinHeap;
heap.insert(9);
heap.insert(5);
heap.insert(3);
heap.insert(6);
heap.insert(7);
heap.insert(2);
heap.insert(8);
heap.insert(1);
heap.insert(4);

while (heap.root) {
    console.log(heap.extract());
}
```

As the overhead of this heap is considerable, it is in practice not as fast as a dynamic-array based heap.

Answer (score 1):

As @trincot answered before, a way to go is to build a linked struct with nodes having `left`, `right`, `parent` pointers to other nodes. This implementation will have an insertion of O(logn) time (because the heap is an [almost complete binary tree](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/complete-vs-almost-complete-binary-tree)). In practical terms, though, it would be rather inefficient as it would require to maintain many (at least 3) pointers per node (aka, a memory overhead of at least 3 * 8 = 24 bytes per item).

Having said that, one can omit the `prev`, `next` pointers (lowering the memory overhead per item) because we can easily compute them (in O(logn) time also).

For example, `next` would be (`prev` is similar):

```java
Node next(Node t)
{
    if (t == null)
       return null;
    if (t.parent == null)
       return t.left; // climb down one level (see @trincot's comment) 
    // if left child, next is my right sibling
    if (t == t.parent.left)
       return t.parent.right;
    // so, i am right child of my parent
    Node p = next(t.parent);
    if (p != null) {
       return p.left;
    } else {
       return null; // no next exists
    } 
}
```

Comment: To make it really equivalent to the `next` pointers, they should link the rightmost node of one level to the left most one on the next level. So the base case `t.parent == null` should be treated separately and return `t.left`. Also, the other solution does not use `right`, so this solution saves one pointer per node at the cost of more processing.

Comment: Yes, i know, it is not equivalent to next pointer in your implementation: it is just the idea of how to compute the next in same level (if it exists)

Comment: `leftmost` would need to know *which* level you want. But with the change I suggested above, all would already work like that. No need for a `leftmost` function. Recursion will do the job.

Comment: @trincot i agree, your suggestion (null parent leaf case) is indeed an elegant solution (so that we dont have to deal with calls to `leftmost` after). I will edit accordingly